# what is wrong with my linear regression neural network

Tags: python, neural-network, linear-regression

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(0)
a = np.random.randint(1,100, size= 1000).reshape(1000,1)
b = np.random.randint(0,2, size=1000).reshape(1000,1)

y = np.where(b==0,a*2, a*3)

X = np.hstack((a,b))
y = y

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

sx = StandardScaler()
X = sx.fit_transform(X)

sy = StandardScaler()
y = sy.fit_transform(y)

w0 = np.random.normal(size=(2,1), scale=0.1)

for i in range(100):
    input_layer = X
    output_layer = X.dot(w0) 

    error = y - output_layer
    square_error = np.sqrt(np.mean(error**2))

    print(square_error)

    w0+= input_layer.T.dot(error)
```

If i understand correctly, linear activation function is always f(x) = x.

If you check this code, you'll see square error is growing and growing, I have no idea how to solve this simple linear problem with NN. I am aware there are other models and libraries, however I am trying to do it this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not incorporate learning rate (see [here](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-learning-rate-in-neural-networks) and a more formal discussion [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent)) into your model. When you train your network, you need to choose a learning rate parameter as well, and it has a big impact on whether your loss will decrease and how fast it converges.

By setting

```
w0+= input_layer.T.dot(error)
```

you chose the learning rate to be 1, which turned out to be too large. If instead you set

```
w0+= 0.0005*input_layer.T.dot(error)
```

(that is, choose learning rate 0.0005) the loss will decrease:

```
1.0017425183
0.521060951473
0.303777564629
0.21993949808
0.193933601196
0.18700323975
0.185262617455
0.184832603515
0.184726763539
.
.
.
```

It won't converge to 0 though, as your model is not linear. In the end the weight `w0` that you get is

```
array([[ 0.92486712],
       [ 0.318241  ]])
```

Comment: Hey Miriam, Once again, thank you very much. You are the best!

Comment: Thanks, happy to help :)